# Lemonbar How to Set Font

Tags: fonts, lemonbar

While I understand `lemonbar -f "FONTNAME"` is supposed to set the font. I am unsure of which fonts I can actually use. I have tried using some fonts from `usr/share/fonts` however, I keep getting the response `could not load font`.

Answer (score 3):

From https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_Logical_Font_Description
I installed  `xorg-xfontsel` and  `xorg-xlsfonts`. From there I was able to set my font for lemonbar. I was using the wrong type of font.

Comment: That answer was very helpful to me. To anyone wondering, you can install this on Ubuntu with `sudo apt-get install xfontsel`, then use with `xfontsel`. This allows you to pick a font, style, size, etc. You'll then be given a string representing that font. Copy/paste that string on `lemonbar -f HERE` and it will work. I had to do this to increase the size of Lemonbar on my Dell XPS 13, because its 4k screen made lemonbar too small and it didn't respect the DPI config on `~/.Xresources`.